# avoid issue in the mvc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

I know that a view shouldn't have any knowledge, of the model or the controller but i am not to sure how to avoid it.

The issue is i am trying to fetch the information from the controller or the model before i need to manipulate it in my view.

Here the code

```
Model     
USER       LOCATION      ARTICLE
id         user_id       title
first      article_id    ...
last
...
```

Relationship

```
user has many locations
article has many locations
location belongs to user
location belongs to article
```

controller

```
@userlocation = @user.locations
```

View

```
<% @userlocation.each do |event| %>
  ...
  <% evTitle = Article.find_by_id(event.article_id) %>
  <%= evTitle.title %>
<% end %>
```

Obviously its not the best not sure how to do the query in the controller, and evTitle doesnt report properly why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In controller you can do like this:

```
@userlocations = @user.locations
@locations_articles = Article.find_all_by_id(@userlocations.map(&:article_id).uniq)
```

Then you can use `@locations_articles` in view. Avoid using `db queries` in view.

```
<% @locations_articles.each do |article| %>
    <%= article.title %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: The only problem, with this is that article_id just refer to the first articles, i dont see the second one and third one

Answer (score 1):

You can first watch the rails cast multiple form episode at here :-

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

and there is an attribute that first you should define in model to access the information at single view form.

def new
  @survey = Survey.new
  3.times do
    question = @survey.questions.build
    4.times { question.answers.build }
  end
end